# Do 10 random forests with 50 trees each on same data, equal one random forest on same data with 500 trees?

Tags: random-forest

I have a data set with 1 million rows.

While running 1 random survival forest containing 500 trees, with the package randomForestSRC in R, it is taking a lot of time due to memory problems.

So, can I run 10 random survival forests with 50 trees on the same data, with different seed each time, and average the results of the 10 random forests (by dividing by 10), so that I can get a reasonably similar result as the one with 500 trees?

Comment: You could do that, but then you would have to average over all the trees from all the models to get similar results. Averaging each model separately is different.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, results should be similar. A random forest is simply a collection of decision trees. Adding more trees later is no problem, as long as you use the same data and parameters with each of your 10 sets of 50 trees. Also, you could look at more efficient versions of the random forest algorithm, e.g. the package ranger, which can also do survival forests, iirc.

Comment: I tried doing so but the accuracy of the 10 random survival forest models on the entire data (by running RFSRC package in R) combined into 1 by averaging them, came out to be much worse than a single 50-tree random survival forest model on the entire data. This seems to be very strange. It seems that there is something wrong happening either with the averaging part or the seed selection part

Comment: Could you provide some code, ideally reproducible, where these results occur? Especially: How exactly did you average the model results?